confused about て無かったら
In the sentence

一部しか残って無かったら意味ないし

Where the  official translation is

Because its meaningless if a part is left

I don't understand how 無かったら isn't negating the 残ってる to mean  "if a part is NOT left"
Shouldn't it be 残ってたら instead?

How are you translating しか?

しか takes a negated verb to produce a meaning of only.
Though when you translate it, the negative is absorbed into the meaning of しか (only).
So, something like,

ひとりしかいない

means, "there's only one".

一部しか残ってなかった

means, "only one part remained"
adding ら

一部しか残ってなかったら意味がない

gets rendered

there's no meaning if only one part remains.


Thank you so much. Makes perfect sense
